# removing a table row in php page(not database) and being able to not display it back after reloading the page

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I have a page called fetch as belllow :

```
$statement = $connection->prepare($query);
  $statement->execute();
  $result = $statement->fetchAll();
  $data = array();
  $filtered_rows = $statement->rowCount();
 foreach($result as $row){

$sub_array = array();
$sub_array[] = $row["id"];
$sub_array[] = $row["first_name"];
$sub_array[] = $row["last_name"];
$sub_array[] = '<input type="checkbox" name="confirm" id="'.$row["id"].'" class="btn btn-danger btn-xs delete"></input>';
$data[] = $sub_array;
}
      $output = array(
     "draw" =>  intval($_POST["draw"]),
"recordsTotal"=> $filtered_rows,
"recordsFiltered"=> get_total_all_records(),
"data"  =>  $data
);   echo json_encode($output);
```

and I have a function  in the index page that calls the delete page :

```
    $(document).on('click', '.delete', function(){
    var user_id = $(this).attr("id");
    if(confirm("Are you sure you want to delete this?"))
    {
        $.ajax({
            url:"delete.php",
            method:"POST",
            data:{user_id:user_id},
            success:function(data)
            {
                alert(data);
                dataTable.ajax.reload();
            }
        });
    }
    else
    {
        return false;   
    }
});
```

and the delete page looks like this :

```
if(isset($_POST["user_id"])){

$statement = $connection->prepare(
    "DELETE FROM users WHERE id = :id"
);
$result = $statement->execute(
    array(
        ':id'   =>  $_POST["user_id"]
    )
);

if(!empty($result))
{
    echo 'Data Deleted';
}}
```

also in the database, I have a table with 4 columns id, first_name, last_name, and check_in (boolean). All I want to do is hide the data displayed from the database if I checkbox them, even after I reload the page. till now I just can delete them. or if I add this function:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $("#myTable").on('click','.del',function(){
     $(this).closest('tr').hide();
     });
 });
```

I can hide them but they came back after I reload the page

Comment: So is the row actually deleted from the database after you execute your delete page code?

Comment: Do you have id's in your tr's?

Comment: yes, right now I just can delete from the database or if use the last function I can hide the rows in  php page but they will come back if I reload the page

Answer (score 0):

@User10 :
(1) Your js at ajax,  data:{user_id:user_id}..where's user_id from your table, cause it's just id
(2) better put dataType: "json" (at ajax)